# How do I resolve "Invitation token can't be blank" for DeviseInvitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using strong_parameters and devise_invitable in my rails application.  If I leave it as it is the "Forbidden Attribute" run time error is what I get.  So I did the following:

1. Created a new controller using `rails g controller users/invitations`
2. Added `:invitations => "users/invitations"` to devise_for
3. Populated users/invitations.rb like so:

   ```
   class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
      def update
       self.resource = resource_class.accept_invitation!(allowed_params)

       if resource.errors.empty?
         set_flash_message :notice, :updated
         sign_in(resource_name, resource)
         respond_with resource, :location => after_accept_path_for(resource)
       else
         respond_with_navigational(resource){ render :edit }
       end
   end

    private

     def allowed_params
        params.permit(:utf8,:authenticity_token,:invitation_token, :_method,
        {user: [:invitation_token,:password,:password_confirmation]}, :commit, 
        :action,:controller)
     end
   end
   ```

However, when I do that I get the error "Invitation token can't be blank".  I've checked the values of allowed_params, using `puts` and it appears that it is there.  Yet, I still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem and answered it on the [wiki](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/wiki/Devise-Invitable-With-Strong-Parameters-Gem).